# Remove ".." from string representation of URL

Tags: iphone, path, nsurl

When you have a filesystem path, you can have a ".." removed (and the previous path component removed as well) by using the `stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath` selector. How can I achieve the same thing for a URL? For example I start out with, say:

```
www.example.com/themes/themeA/../common/assetA.png
```

Which I need converted to:

```
www.example.com/themes/common/assetA.png
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a URL use the NSURL method:

```
- (NSURL *)standardizedURL
```

Returns a new URL that points to the same resource as the original URL and is an absolute path.

Example:

```
NSString *s  = @"www.example.com/themes/themeA/../common/assetA.png";
NSURL    *u  = [NSURL URLWithString:s];
NSURL    *su = [u standardizedURL];
NSLog(@"su: %@", su);
```

NSLog output:

```
su: www.example.com/themes/common/assetA.png
```

Answer (score 2):

What about the following?

```
NSString* resolved_url 
    = [[[NSURL URLWithString: @"www.example.com/themes/themeA/../common/assetA.png"] standardizedURL] absoluteString];
```

If you want `NSURL` instead of `NSString`, remove call to `absoluteString`.

Comment: Ah, correct. It's `standardizedURL`. Fixed answer. Thanks for pointing out.